# how to get immediate recyclerview item from firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

Pls help in getting this,I just want when user add content on firebase this particular node will display in recyclerview and whech user click on cross on recycler item it can be deleted

```
private fun insetcontent(bannerText: String, titelText: String, designationtext: String, descriptionText1: String) {

    var databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Content")

    var key = databaseReference.push().key!!

    var hasmap:MutableMap<String,String> = hashMapOf(
        "contentId" to key,
        "movieImage" to "default",
        "bannerName" to bannerText,
        "titleName" to titelText,
        "designation_text" to designationtext,
        "description" to descriptionText1,



    )
    databaseReference.child(key).setValue(hasmap).addOnCompleteListener {
        if (it.isSuccessful) {
            view?.content_progressbasr!!.visibility = View.GONE
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Content added successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show()
            databaseReference.addChildEventListener(object : ChildEventListener{
                override fun onChildAdded(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
                 for(snapshotone in snapshot.)
                 {
                     var listadata = snapshotone.getValue(ContentClass::class.java)
                     list.add(listadata!!)
                 }
                    view!!.content_recyclerview.apply {
                        var contentadapter = ContentAdapter(list,requireView())
                        this.adapter = contentadapter
                    }
                }

                override fun onChildChanged(
                    snapshot: DataSnapshot,
                    previousChildName: String?
                ) {

                }

                override fun onChildRemoved(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                }

                override fun onChildMoved(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {

                }

                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

                }

            })
        } else {
            view?.content_progressbasr!!.visibility = View.GONE
            Toast.makeText(
                requireContext(),
                "error : ${it.exception.toString()}",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }
    }

}
```

above is my firebase logic and again i just want last added child will display in recyclerview

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: it does not show child in recyclerview which is just added by user ,so that he can review his submitted response if it not suitable then he delete this node .

Comment: This is type of behiviour i am  expecting from this code after adding addchildvalueeventlistener immediatlly  adding the child ,pls help me sir